# Maximized portlet, custom max.tpl

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, liferay, portlet

I'm working on a JSF portlet, which uses

```
javax.portlet.WindowState.MAXIMIZED
```

after a form has been posted.

Method:

```
private void setPortletMaximized(boolean maximized) {
    
    FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    javax.faces.context.ExternalContext externalContext = facesContext.getExternalContext();
    javax.portlet.PortletResponse portletResponse = (javax.portlet.PortletResponse)externalContext.getResponse();
    javax.portlet.ActionResponse actionResponse = (javax.portlet.ActionResponse)portletResponse;
    try {
        if(maximized){
            actionResponse.setWindowState(javax.portlet.WindowState.MAXIMIZED);
        }else {
            actionResponse.setWindowState(javax.portlet.WindowState.NORMAL);
        }
        
    } catch (WindowStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Problem is that I need to use a custom "max.tpl" for this portlet ONLY. Is there a way to pass a custom layout from my method? Is it possible in any way?

Comment: I'm not an expert on Liferay layouts, but you may be able to change the layout programmatically with [LayoutLocalServiceUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/LayoutLocalServiceUtil.html). Also, [this forum post](https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/5181568) explains how to change the layout for all portlets, but I don't think that is what you want.

Comment: Why do you need the portlet specific layout template? Can you describe the requirement. Layout templates are a powerful feature, but they are only rarely used to customize an individual portlet.

Comment: @TomášPiňos I needed one "max.tpl" with a specifik feature (this case, breadcrumbs), and others without (but the one with specifik feature could be used by other portlets aswell). Solved it by creating breadcrumbs in the portlet for now. It's not an optimal solution for our needs.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to show breadcrumbs for some instances of your portlet only. Right?

In your JSPs or facelets, you probably use something similar to this snippet:

```
<%@taglib prefix="liferay-ui" uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" %>

<liferay-ui:breadcrumb/>
```

**Make your portlet configurable**

A straightforward implementation would be to make your portlet configurable. The admin would be able to configure whether to show the breadcrumbs for each portlet instance. See [Implementing Configurable Portlet Preferences](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/implementing-configurable-portlet-prefer-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-03-en) for details.

**Or... use Nested Portlets Portlet**

You could also use [Nested Portlets Portlet](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Nested+Portlets+Portlet) to achieve the variability. Place Nested Portlets Portlet to the page, use a suitable layout template (1 column, 2 columns, ...) and place Breadcrumbs portlet above / next to your portlet just where you need it.

```
 ----------------------
| Breadcrumbs portlet  |
|----------------------|
| Your portlet         |
 ----------------------
```

Personally I like Nested Portlets Portlet very much - but only for a very small subset of problems. Usually I prefer other solutions like making your portlet configurable.

**Then...**

Depending on your requirements - maybe you don't need the nesting at all. Wouldn't it be enough just to place the portlets one above / next to the other?